# How to open ".z" file in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I have a plaintext file named `~/.z` but when I open it with `emacs --no-init-file`, I get  a blank buffer and a buffer named *jka-compr-error* which states

```
Error while executing "gzip -c -q -d < /home/username/.z"

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
```

How can I open this file in emacs?

Comment: I'm using emacs version 25.2.2

Comment: I have a file named .z because of https://github.com/rupa/z

Comment: try with `--no-init-file`

Comment: I did, same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off `auto-compression-mode` in your `.emacs` file: `(auto-compression-mode 0)`, and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Use `find-file-literally`. It does no conversions and it does not use the `auto-mode-alist` to set the major mode: it uses `fundamental-mode` instead.

Answer (score 0):

.z is an unix compression file extension.

So probably you cant open it. But you can always extract it but i think extracting would not be the case here since you said thats a plaintext file.